# R - How create a variable based in another variable

Tags: r

I have:

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)
```

and I want create `v2` which assigns to `v1` the number of sets of 3 elements:

```
v2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2)
```

Explanation:

For the first three times a number is repeated the value corresponding to that number is a 1, for the second three times it's a 2, and so on.

Comment: You should at least tag this with which language you are using, and probably include more information in the question along those lines too

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry... the language is R

Comment: are there only clusters of 3-elements in your v1 data? every sequence is multiple of 3 or not?

Comment: Dear Richard, don't you undertand the logic of v2? Don't you know how can I create v2?

Comment: @JoseQuesada I've tried to improve the explanation. Plese review if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes Agenis, every sequence is multiple of 3.

Comment: Your result alludes me. Might be morning sickness, lack of coffee or something third. Can you put down the exact algorithm that converts `v1` to `v2`?

Answer (score 5):

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)
```

Use `rle` to find the run lengths:

```
l <- rle(v1)$lengths
#[1] 3 3 9 6
```

Create a sequence 1:n for each run length n:

```
s <- sequence(l)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Use integer division:

```
(s - 1) %/% 3 + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: This would be a great question/answer if more than two people knew what the question is asking. +1.  I've been `rle`ing this for too long already.

Comment: @RichardScriven It was kind of hard to parse the explanation.

Comment: Oh yes Roland, your answer is brilliant. sorry if I have not explained the question very well.